# Loading same data files one by one in Database table in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 6 files with named with Data_20190823101010,Data_20190823101112,Data_20190823101214,Data_20190823101310,Data_20190823101410,Data_20190823101510.

These are daily files to be loaded into a SQL Server DB table.

Due to size and performance reasons need to load one by one.

Python code must pick one file at a time,process and load into DB Table.

How to write the code? 
Thanks in advance.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

#folder_name = 'Data_Folder'
file_type = 'csv'
file_titles = ['C1','C2','C3',C4','C5']
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None,skiprows=1,names=file_titles,low_memory=False) for f in glob.glob(folder_name + "//*Data_*" )])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import those csv files in a dataframe and then concatenate and use pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function to connect and upload the data to MS SQL Server DB

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import glob


connection= urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=Server_name;DATABASE=DB Name")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(connection))

path = r'C:\file_path' # local drive File path
all_csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")


for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df.to_sql('Table_Name', schema='dbo', con = engine)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using this. But I want to load file by file.... without concatenation.

Comment: Then don't do `pd.concat`.  Put the whole script in a `for-loop`: `for f_name in file_names:` etc...

Comment: @PythonWizard Updated my answer, Now it's reading each file in the directory and uploading to dataframe first and then exporting to SQL Server

Comment: Hi @min2bro. Thanks. I want to process to load from source to SQL Server DB table. Once it is finish, should start second file to load....

Comment: @Trenton_M, Please help me to provide the load.

Comment: @PythonWizard As far as I can see, @min2bro has set the script up correctly, but you have to properly set `connection` to your database.